# ssh over jump server issues

Tags: windows, ssh, jumphost

I want to be able to run this command from a windows machine. I use it to connect
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i secret.pem -J user@jump.host.ip.ad user@target.host.ip.ad "ls"

ssh on the jump host is setup so that I dont need to specify credentials.
Both jump host and target host are Ubuntu machines.

I am able to run the command successfully from my mac but not from my windows machine. It keeps asking for user password.
Now when i try:
ssh -i secret.pem user@jump.host.ip.ad
ssh user@target.host.ip.ad
from windows it works. But as i want to run the command in automated way it want serve me here.
But setup works.
Why isn't ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i secret.pem -J user@jump.host.ip.ad user@target.host.ip.ad "ls" working from windows machine?
Also yes i tried chatGPT.